# Combining two nginx hosts into one

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to combine these hosts into one?

```
server {
   server_name www.website.com;
   rewrite ^ http://website.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
   server_name www.website.ru;
   rewrite ^ http://website.ru$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, the following should work:

```
server {
  server_name www.website.com website.com www.website.ru website.ru;

  if ( $host ~ "www\.(.*)" ) {
    set $hostdomain $1;
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$hostdomain$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  # handling of the non-rewritten non-www requests goes here
}
```

note: the reason you need to save the domain-minus-www instead of using $1 directly in the rewrite is because the rewrite directive resets the capture variables

Comment: You can notice that the redirect host can be com or ru. I need to make it depend from the original URL